# How do you keep the password hidden when invoked during the su command?

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, su

This is the first time it has happened to me where I am using the su command and it actually displays the password on the terminal and doesn't stay hidden. Here is my code snippet:

```
 sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"
```

Code explanation: 
I am accessing a remote server and trying be root on that server to create a folder. In doing so I have to use the su command and it prompts me for the password. When I enter the password, it gets displayed and doesn't stay hidden. How do I fix that?

Comment: Use sudo don't use `su` here.

Comment: @slm sudo doesn't work. I keep getting an error every time I use it.

Comment: Do you have `sudo` setup to run this?

Comment: @slm Yes I do, but it still is giving me an error

Comment: If you use the command `sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"`, does it work? `su` turns off echo on its tty, but when `ssh` is given a command to run on the remote host, it doesn't allocate a tty unless it is given a `-t` option.

Answer (score 3):

In general please ***AVOID*** using sshpass with a password. 
Everything you wrote can be observed by other users with the ps command and this ***SHOULD*** be of concern to you. 
Second problem there is here, I don't see you specifying ***-t*** option. This means you have ***disabled***

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

In your /etc/sudoers, which can have security implications.

If you still insist on using sshkeypass, try:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -qt username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"
```

You can set up easily a generate ssh key just to do this job and then remove it.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Follow the instructions on the screen,

```
ssh-copy-id user@server1
```

Or you can also do:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@server1 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. use `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` at `username@74.11.11.11` to login remotely, without interactive password, instead of having the password on command line from client machine. This would also allow the job to run automatedly via cron or whatever.
2. configure `/etc/sudoers` on remote box `74.11.11.11` to allow the command to execute as root user, by the user that is connecting, in this case: `username`.

So in your example, `/etc/sudoers` on `74.11.11.11` would allow user `username` to execute `mkdir`, as `root` without a password.

If you have tried this, and it is not working for you, run `man sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the suggestions to not use `sshpass`, it's possible to keep it "hidden" from the command line:

- Edit your `/etc/profile`  and paste there:

  ```
  export SSHPASS='my_pass_here'
  ```
- Use the `-e` argument with `sshpass` command

  ```bsh
  $ sshpass -e ssh usernmane@hosting.example 'ls -ll'
  ```
- Another option is to save your password in a different file and use the `-f` argument:

  ```bsh
  $ sshpass -f password_filename ssh usernmane@hosting.example 'ls -la'
  ```

But the best solution is to follow the [@Hristo Mohamed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170548/hristo-mohamed) [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283561/150314):

> In general please AVOID using sshpass with a password.

> You can set up easily a generate ssh key just to do this job and then remove it.